# Count no of site visitors and store it in database?

Tags: asp.net

I would like a solution on how to count the no of site visitors for my ASP.NET web application. I would then like advice on how to store this in a database.

What resources, tutorials, etc can help get me started in this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the Global.asax file

in your **global.asax** file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs on application startup
Application["NoOfVisitors"] = 0;
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs when a new session is started
Application.Lock();
Application["NoOfVisitors"] = (int)Application["NoOfVisitors"] + 1;
Application.UnLock();
}
```

**aspx page**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<b>No of Visits:</b>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
  { 
    lblCount.Text = Application["NoOfVisitors"].ToString();
    var cnnString =         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var cmd = "insert into Table values(@Count)";
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, cnn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count",lblCount.Text);

            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: my friend i can able to show the values also..i need to store the values in db.....

Comment: @PrasadRaja:now i have added your requirement..!! check it and tell

Comment: as per your logic..whenever page is refresh, values storing the database.... in case server memory get clear & some crash has been happen.... when i restart all these stuff...again it will count from first & db values it wil update...planing to avoid such situation

Comment: @PrasadRaja:then do it in some button click..!!

Comment: no i dont want to do it on button click. when the page is visited ...values need to update automatically

Comment: @then do it in if(!IsPostBack)